# Is there a utility that does the opposite of ilmerge?

Tags: .net, ilmerge, disassembly, .net-assembly, assembly-references

I would like to strip code from an assembly using a command-line or GUI. There are times when assemblies contain types that are in other assemblies and this requires you to add **extern alias** to your code (which isn't that big of a deal). The alternative is recompilation from source (if available) into separate assemblies or stripping code the assembly in some way, and adding back references in the "main" assembly.

I guess I'm looking for ilunmerge. Does anyone know of such a utility?

Comment: I do not know of any, but it should be easy-peasy to write one yourself.

Comment: I am intrigued to know why you would often need to shred and reassemble assemblies. Just curious.

Comment: This wouldn't be often. In fact because it's not often is why I was hoping something was out there. The case I'm looking at is removing Castle from Rhino Mocks 3.6 (Rhino Mocks 3.5 comes with Castle in or out). For now, I've recompiled Rhino from source which produces the Castle-less version.

Comment: Why would you want to manipulate the assembly directly if you can recompile from source?

Comment: I was trying to be lazy. I ended up with the source route. Of course if anyone needs this capability with no source available, then I guess that means one of the manual methods below :)

Comment: That's a perfectly legitimate requirement. Some binaries don't have sources or don't build on current platforms. They could have had ILMerge'd old libraries and you might need an upgrade etc. Makes sense but as I understand it's not straightforward, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

[Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) is another tool that will let you disassemble your binaries.